# how to show $http error status in a table?

Tags: angularjs

How to display error status when trying to loop through an array of objects from the server to display some data, but somehow the $http request encounters some error? I was trying to modify this code I found online but can't seem to show the error in it if I change the server name.

```
<body>    
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">         
        <ul>            
            <li ng-repeat="x in myData">
            enter code here`{{ x.Name + ', ' + x.Country }}
            </li>            
        </ul>        
    </div>        
    <script>        
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {            
            $http.get("customers.php").then(function (response) {
            $scope.myData = response.data.records;
            });            
        });        
    </script>    
</body>
```

Here, I'm not able to print the error status if I change the server name to some incorrect one.

Answer (score 0):

From the angular docs

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

```
// Simple GET request example:
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/someUrl'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
```

so in your case

```
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
$http.get("customers.php").then(function (response) {
$scope.myData = response.data.records;
},
function errorCallback(response) {
    //do something with error
      })

);
</script>
```

Comment: this seems to work perfectly if I create another table to display the error status retrieved through the errorCallback method!

Comment: you probably want o display some king of error when there is an error at fetching instead of adding the raw error to table